# Convert string slice to int in Rust

Tags: string, integer, type-conversion, rust

> **Note** The code in this question pertains to a version of Rust before 1.0 but the answers have been updated for Rust 1.0.

I have trouble converting a string to an integer.

```
fn main() {
    let input_text = io::stdin()
        .read_line()
        .ok()
        .expect("failed to read line");

    let input: Option<int> = from_str(input_text.as_slice());

    println!("{}", input);
}
```

I enter a number on the console (42 for example) and my program prints `None`.

[The documentation says](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/from_str/trait.FromStr.html) that that is a normal situation when the string is ill-formatted, but what's wrong with my `42`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can call [`str::parse()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse), but you need to make sure that `read_line` is working. We need a reader:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let reader = io::stdin();
}
```

[`stdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.stdin.html) reads the global buffer that handles the input stream and also implements the [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) trait which has the [`read_line` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) method. This takes a  mutable `String` as an input buffer and reads all bytes from the stream  until a newline byte is reached and appends them to the buffer. The [`#expect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) method unwraps the `Result`; if it is an `Err` it will panic with the message and the cause.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut input_text = String::new();
    reader.read_line(&mut input_text).expect("failed to read line");
}
```

We now have the input text that we want to convert into an `i32`. This is where `str::parse()` will work for us, as long as we give it a type to parse to. [`str::trim()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) is necessary because `read_line` includes the newline byte  the buffer

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut input_text = String::new();
    reader.read_line(&mut input_text).expect("failed to read line");
    let input = input_text.trim().parse::<i32>();
}
```

We're not done yet, we still need to ensure that we successfully parsed the input using pattern matching. All the code you need to convert your original input buffer into a usable integer is:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut input_text = String::new();

    reader.read_line(&mut input_text).expect("failed to read line");

    let input_opt = input_text.trim().parse::<i32>();

    let input_int = match input_opt {
        Ok(input_int) => input_int,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("please input a number ({})", e);
            return;
        }
    };

    println!("{}", input_int);
}
```

This compiles without errors or warnings.

Answer (score 8):

The input includes a newline at the end, as explained in the documentation for [`read_line`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Buffer.html#method.read_line). This causes `from_str()` to fail. Using `std::str::trim()` and changing this:

```
let input: Result<i32, _> = input_text.parse();
```

into this:

```
let input: Result<i32, _> = input_text.trim().parse();
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

As of Rust 1.14, [*The Rust Programming Language* has this example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/guessing-game.html):

```
let guess: u32 = guess.trim().parse()
    .expect("Please type a number!");
```

You can also just use the same variable name again and the new type will "shadow" the old type:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input_text = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_text)
        .expect("failed to read line");

    let input: u32 = input_text.trim().parse()
        .expect("Please type a number!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
fn main() {
    let input_text = std::old_io::stdin()
        .read_line()
        .ok()
        .expect("failed to read line");
    let input_number: Option<i32> = input_text.trim().parse().ok();
    let number = match input_number{
        Some(num) => num,
        None => {
            println!("Wrong input data! Input a number.");
            return;
        }
    };
    println!("{}", number);
}
```

Comment: This answer refers to the `old_io` module, which is not available in Rust 1.0; this answer is no longer useful.

Answer (score -1):

For converting the string to integer we use trim and parse. The trim() method on Strings will eliminate any whitespace at the beginning and end of our string.

This means that if we type 5 and hit return, guess looks like this: 5\n. The \n represents ‘newline’, the enter key. trim() gets rid of this, leaving our string with only the 5.

The parse() method on strings parses a string into some kind of number. Since it can parse a variety of numbers, we need to give Rust a hint as to the exact type of number we want. Hence, let a_int: i32. The colon (:) after guess tells Rust we’re going to annotate its type. i32 is an integer, thirty-two-bit integer.  We use the expect() method to crash if there’s an error.

```
 let a_int: i32 = input_1.trim().parse()
 .ok()
 .expect("Please type a number!");
```

Ref:

- https://users.rust-lang.org/t/from-string-to-integer/3632
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/guessing-game.html